# Permalinked posts blank after WordPress migrated to Nginx from Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, permalinks

Background:

- Server is Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.04.04 running Nginx
- nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 19:40:28)
- URL of the Wordpress is [DocoSacramento.com](http://docosacramento.com)
- Wordpress was migrated from an Apache server
- Pages work great! (such as http://docosacramento.com/explore/dine/ or http://www.docosacramento.com/about/)
- **Issue: Posts show up as blank white pages when visited** (such as http://www.docosacramento.com/blog/grandest-openings-punch-bowl-social/ or http://www.docosacramento.com/news/another-sales-milestone-residences-sawyer-penthouses-sold/)
- The posts follow the permalink structure of "**docosacramento.com/%category%/%postname%/**" (refer to the following image for a visual) [permalinks settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sz1r.png)

My **Nginx Server Block** is currently as follows:

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/docosacramento.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name docosacramento.com www.docosacramento.com;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location /news {
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri /news/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_cache_key $host$request_method$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that perhaps location blocks are needed for each of the 4 post categories this website has (which are news, blog, gallery, and press-release) so I created a `location /news {...` block for testing but that does not seem to have made any changes when visiting posts that begin with `/news/`. Also, I've been sure to run the following commands each time I've edited the Nginx server block:

- `sudo nginx -t`
- `sudo service nginx restart`
- `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Is there anything else I can try or test? Are there any logs or additional information I can provide? Please let me know!

**Update - Error messages from switching Wordpress debugging on, revised after debugging a few of the easy ones:**

> Strict Standards: Declaration of sidebar_walker::start_el() should be
>   compatible with Walker_Page::start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0,
>   $args = Array, $current_page = 0) in
>   /var/www/docosacramento.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/downtown-commons/functions.php
>   on line 0
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of
>   themeslug_walker_nav_menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with
>   Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in
>   /var/www/docosacramento.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/downtown-commons/functions.php
>   on line 0
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /var/www/docosacramento.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/downtown-commons/single-post.php
>   on line 52

**Final Update after Resolving Issue**
Line 34 in single-post.php has been updated to:

`<?php } ?>`, was previously `<? }?>`

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Comment: Hey Kamal, I switched my Wordpress debugging on and I receive some errors at the top of my pages. It is too long to fit in a comment so I will update the original post. Let me know if that gives you any insight

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/docosacramento.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/downtown-commons/single-post.php on line 52 - check this file as per the error log.. Make sure that you don't have such error then try to access page..

Comment: Thanks, working on this file is eventually what solved the problem. Thanks for suggesting looking at error logs!

Comment: I am glad to know.

Comment: I've voted to put this on hold, since the solution was that short tags are not supported in the new server. I don't think new questions with that answer are useful for new readers, and it has undoubtedly been covered on the web before. I am also not sure what they would search for to bring them here.

Comment: Why would you put a solution on hold that solved the problem? I noted it as such so visitors who come across this are clear that I’m not in need of additional suggestions.